# Why is this asp repeater inserting an extra <li> (or <tr>) into every "ItemTemplate"

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

The asp.net repeater is inserting an extra `<li></li>` into every `<ItemTemplate>`. It does the same thing with tables. It inserts an extra `<tr></tr>`. And same with divs. Basically any element that I put in the ItemTemplate comes out with a duplicate.

Here is my code.

This is part of that builds the `litData` the aspx.vb file:

```
If item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
    Dim drv As System.Data.DataRowView = DirectCast((e.Item.DataItem), System.Data.DataRowView)
    Dim strLinkValue As String = drv.Row("ReturnVal").ToString()
    Dim Literal1 As Literal = DirectCast(item.FindControl("litData"), Literal)
    Literal1.Text = "<a href=" & strQString.ToLower().Replace("/default.aspx", "") & strLinkValue & "/default.aspx>Hello World" + strLinkValue + "</a>"
End If
```

And this is in the .aspx file:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptData" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptData_OnItemDataBound" EnableViewState="false">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li><asp:Literal ID="litData" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am expecting it to render...

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What is actually rendering...

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li></li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How are you databinding it?

Comment: @Andrei `OnItemDataBound="rptData_OnItemDataBound"` and in the code behind I have `rptData.DataSource = objDS` and on next line,  `rptData.DataBind()`. I'm not extremely familiar with asp.net :) I am mainly working on this just do clean up the html.

Comment: OnItemDataBound is code that executes AFTER the item is data bound. There's no need to rebind it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment you are binding data to the repeater inside `ItemDataBound` handler. That is not the right way to do it. Move your data binding to the `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // other code

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        rptData.DataSource = objDS;
        rptData.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And you might not need the Item Bound handler anymore